# Access Control Allow Origin Header Issue

Tags: apache, cors, httpd.conf

I'm having an issue with setting CORS header to the configuration file, httpd.conf.

I've followed the instructions from documentations and stack overflow help.

Here's what I've done so far:

1) Checking header modules (making sure it's uncommented)

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

2) Set CORS Header for Origin Allow in httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted

#
# Allowing CORS Header Access Control Allow Origin
#
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" --- **Added This line here**
</Directory>
```

3) Restarted Windows Apache using GUI

I keep getting this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It seems that the suggestions above from Googling-fu are not working at all. Much appreciated for help in advance!

EDIT: Fixed formatting

Comment: You don’t have `&ltDirectory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects"&gt` in the actual .htaccess file, right? You have `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects">`?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I do have that part in httpd.conf file. Ignore the symbol part. I was trying to format the post here.